# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CountriesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can pass in an ID number but when I have the code below i get the error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CountriesController#home

```
 def home
   @pin = Country.last
   @countries = Country.all
   #<the issue is on this line below>
   @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
   gon.lat = @pin.latitude
   gon.lon = @pin.longitude
   gon
   gon.countries = @countries
 end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked params[:country_id]. Is it nil or have some value? Or there is no record with that country id.

Comment: It works when i do it like this! @country = Country.find_by(params[:country_id])

Comment: @user3457760 it wont throw an error if you use find_by but should you be making sure that such situation doesn't occur?

Comment: What I'd suggest is that you contact StackOverflow through the contact us link at the bottom of the page and ask to be "disassociated" from that -31 posting. Then you get your rep back. Please do the reading suggested, and understand that until you got personal everything was in good faith. After this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296821/1927206 the Meta hordes gleefully stomped on you. Try to stick with it and move on from what has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error if it could not find a `Country` with that ID in the database.

You should check a few things:

- Is `params[:country_id]` nil?
- In a terminal, run `rake routes`, find your route and check if there's indeed a `:country_id` parameter in it. Also see the [routing documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code).
- If `params[:country_id]` is not nil, there might not be such a country in your database.

See the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object) for more information.